# Cannot run screen command via ss2 in PHP

Tags: php

```
$conn = ssh2_connect($ip, $port);
ssh2_auth_password($conn, $user, $pass);

$stream = ssh2_exec($conn, "screen -dmS check");
stream_set_blocking($stream, true);
$stream_out = ssh2_fetch_stream($stream, SSH2_STREAM_STDIO);
return stream_get_contents($stream_out);
```

This script is not working and it isn't creating screen. Help.

Comment: You'll need an error message to debug this code. See PHP docs for temporarily enabling reporting and display of errors while debugging: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php#85096

Comment: There is no any error message or any output :(

Answer (score 0):

I can add also, that from bash site, it successfully logs to sshd service, accepted and authenticated successfully.

Also searching answer for this type of issue.

Script uses also other non root user, so there can be issue, but therefore in my scripts all worked with your syntax.